# split state in redux

Tags: javascript, redux

I've a state in redux that start to be very complex and hard to maintain:

```
const state = {
  Mode: [
    ['foo', 
      {
        prop2: [{id: id, otherValue: otherValue}],
        id: 0
      }
    ], ['bar', 
      {
        prop3: [{id: id, otherValue: otherValue}],
      }
    ]]
}
```

For example, when I want to add a value to prop3, I've a map in a map in a map.

I would to split this state into multiple reducers in order to have simpler reducers.

Usually, I use multiple reducers when different part of state are not related:

`UserReducer`, `PostReducer`, `CommentReducer`: These reducers for example are not related and can be updated separately.
In my case, the state and the different part are related.
What's the good way to simplify the update of a part of the state ?
Do some tools like reselect can help ?

Comment: Do you *really* need `Mode` to be an **array**, that contains **arrays** ? Can't you use objects for `foo` and `bar` (`Mode: [ { foo: { prop2: [/*...*/] } }, /*...*/]`)

Comment: Yes I need because order is important in my case.  But this is an example and my state is more complex that that. See that as an "collection of tupple"

Comment: https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/SplittingReducerLogic.html It look I'm concerned with slice reducers

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/738 I think this close my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simplify your state shape, normalizing it, as you can see [here](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html). For example, if the order of your Mode element is important, you can split it in two parts: one part of state containing the list of 'modes' and the other part containing the order. Like this:

```
Modes: { 
        foo: { prop2:[/*...*/] },
        bar: { prop3:[/*...*/] },
        /*...*/
      },
Order: { 
        foo: 1,
        bar: 0,
        /*...*/
      },
```

And the ordering task is performed by the selector who retrieve the Mode portion of you state.
However, to manage complex state shape you can use [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/): it helps you to update portion of state in complicated nested object, without affecting other properties

Comment: I finally use normalizr to normalize my state shape. It leads to smaller reducer. It also leads to other issues (delete an entity with its child becomes non-trivial)